# How to only drop constraints located in Constraints folder for specific table

Tags: sql, constraints, azure-sql-database

I need to have a statement/procedure on how to **only** drop constraints that show up in the `Constraints` folder in the database structure. If I go through the information `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`it contains all the constraints like PKs and FKs but I just need to delete the ones from here as they define `DEFAULT 0` for certain columns.

Any help appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following script:

```
select
'ALTER TABLE '+QUOTENAME(object_schema_name(parent_object_id))+'.'+QUOTENAME(object_name(parent_object_id))
+' DROP CONSTRAINT '+QUOTENAME(sdc.name)+''
from sys.default_constraints sdc
```